# phpMyAdmin login is not working after changing port number

Tags: mysql, django, nginx, phpmyadmin, apache2

I have deployed django project on ubuntu server using `nginx` and `gunicorn`. Django tries to route `/phpmyadmin` within django project which blocks access to phpmyadmin. So, I changed to different port number and allowed it though `vestacp` firewall as well as added `Listen 99` to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file.

Now `phpMyAdmin` loads to new port but login with correct username and password doesn't work. Though returns token with correct credentials without error redirects to login page again. And returns error message with wrong credentials.

- [Change phpMyAdmin port from 80 to another number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896988/change-phpmyadmin-port-from-80-to-another-number)

Edit:

- No error message shows in phpmyadmin
- Login works with `host_address:port/phpmyadmin` but not working with `domain.com:port/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Do you have any errors in phpmyadmin or php logs?

Comment: No error message shows in phpmyadmin